# Multi nested (Recursive) Query like inheritance

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table with some categories and those categories will have some child categories and these child categories may have their own children and this flow will continue to an unknown number of Childs or parents.

For example I have two main categories and these two category having 5 child categories and these 5 have their own 15 children's (3 for each) and the 15 children categories may have some children and so on...

I need a query to find out all the children associated with their parent category please see the image below.

[image]

I've tried the solutions similar to this case from stack overflow but nothing works for me as I want to do.

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) Please post data as formatted text, not images. That allows people to copy and paste it out for testing. Better still provide DDL/DML statements (temp table creation + population). 2) Please show us what you have tried even if its not working.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the mistakes I've made with this question. I'll try to avoid this kind of mistakes next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on expected output, I don't think there is any requirement to use recursion. A simple left join would do the job.

See below :

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_CATEGORY(
ID INT,
NAME NVARCHAR(256),
PARENT INT,
is_parent NVARCHAR(3));

INSERT INTO CAR_CATEGORY(ID,NAME,PARENT,is_parent) VALUES
(1,'AUTO Sector',0,'yes'),
(2,'4 wheelers',1,'yes'),
(3,'Cars',2,'yes'),
(4,'Diesel cars',3,'yes'),
(5,'Petrol cars',3,'yes'),
(6,'CNG cars',3,'yes'),
(7,'Suzuki Diesel cars',4,'no'),
(8,'TATA Petrol cars',5,'yes'),
(9,'TATA Nexon',8,'no')

SELECT 
   CAR_CAT1.NAME ParentCategory, 
   COALESCE(CAR_CAT2.NAME,'No child') AS ChildCategory
FROM 
   CAR_CATEGORY CAR_CAT1
LEFT JOIN CAR_CATEGORY CAR_CAT2 ON
   CAR_CAT1.ID = CAR_CAT2.Parent
WHERE 
   CAR_CAT1.is_parent = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer is helpful but not working correctly when I have a large amount of data . this is excluding all the data which level is after grand child. But I can provide a sample data of my table. thanks again

Comment: Are you looking to get the full list of descendants for each parent in your hierarchy? Like Parent, Child, Grand child etc?

Comment: yes correct! but I don't know how many children or its level I'll have because all the data is dynamic and may have N number of level. where N= any +ve number.

Comment: If I understood correctly, on the left column you would only have the parents node, and the list of its children on the right column?

Comment: yes right, but a child could also be a parent. so in that case that will be in both first in child column and after that in parent column for its child.

Comment: Shouldn't 'Auto sector' have Both '4 wheelers' and 'cars' in the sample output you gave then?

Comment: I think that example is not explaining my case well. I'll provide you the exact case with my output in real query.

Comment: Allright. I'll let you edit your question first before I try anything.

Comment: @Nads . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  There are grandchildren in the data, but no grandchildren in the results shown.  I would suggest that you accept this answer (if it actually works) and ask a *new* question that is more complete.